# Opening terminal with multiple tabs using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux shell script. I want to write a shell script which will open terminal with multiple tabs. And in each tab it should run one rtsp client app.

i have written this code,

```
tab="--tab-with-profile=Default -e "
cmd="java RunRTSPClient"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
   do
#   
   foo="$foo $tab $cmd"         
   done
gnome-terminal $foo
exit 0
```

Its executing fine but it will open terminal and immediately it is closing.(I am not getting errors)
If I replaced the line `foo=...` with `gnome-terminal --tab -e $cmd` then its working fine but opens independent terminal.

suggest me how to fix this.

thank you

Comment: I don't think you want one `gnome-terminal` with multiple `--tab` arguments; rather you want multiple `gnome-terminal --tab` invocations.

Comment: I read one blog that says, put all commands in a strig and give it to gnome-terminal. it will open the tabs and runs the app. Thats why i am trying this. I need to open more than 100 tabs for my testing. writing multiple times --tab -e won't be good.

Comment: Ah you might be right, however I don't think it will make that much difference to performance doing it the way I suggest.  Give it a try at least.

Comment: Yes, I have tried already, it was working fine. But I need to type for 100 time --tab -e. Just I am trying to reduce this copy paste work.

Comment: Oh dear; let me try an answer then.

Comment: Quote `$cmd` as `foo="$foo $tab '$cmd'"`

Comment: @anishsane That won't actually work correctly unless it's eval'd (which introduces security problems). String-splitting doesn't process quotes as syntactic; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: ...by the way, there's an OS-level limit to total command-line length (varies with your operating system and the size of the set of defined environment variables [which are also allocated out of the same region], so we can't reliably tell you what it would be). If you want to specify literally 100 tabs this way, that could be over it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I am asking about quoting, _while passing to gnome-terminal_. to my knowledge, `-e` takes one argument. e.g. `-e vim /etc/passwd` will open only vim. Whereas `-e "vim /etc/passwd"` will open the file in vim.

Comment: @anishsane But setting `foo="gnome-terminal -e "vim /etc/passwd"` and running `$foo` doesn't run <`gnome-terminal`> <`-e`> <`vim /etc/passswd`>. Instead, it runs <`gnome-terminal`> <`-e`> <`"vim`> <`/etc/passwd"`>. The quotes are treated as data, not syntax, during shell string-splitting. Seriously, read the FAQ I linked.

Comment: @user1241903 I suggest that you show a single `gnome-terminal` command that opens several tabs at once. I can give you an answer that will scriptably create the same `argv` array as any hand-built command line... but knowing exactly what the hand-built command line should be is a gnome-terminal question, not a bash question, and out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: gnome-terminal is not included in foo. Only arguments are included in foo. (as per his code) even your answer 1 hr ago asks to quote the command given as next argument to `-e`.

Comment: @anishsane Yes, but my answer uses quotes as SYNTAX to separate array elements, which is a completely different thing from putting quotes within a string as DATA. This is very clearly explained in the FAQ, which I've pointed to enough times to be tiring of repeating myself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32767/discussion-between-anishsane-and-charles-duffy)

Comment: @user1241903 Why don't you link us to this blog you read?

Answer (score 5):

You should always (always!) use an array for building up argument lists in bash.

That is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#    ^^ this has to be bash, not /bin/sh, for arrays to work
cmd=( gnome-terminal )
for ((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
  cmd+=( --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient" )
done
"${cmd[@]}"
```

This will give you the exact equivalent of running:

```
gnome-terminal \
  --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default -e "java RunRTSPClient"
```

...which is what I understand that you want.

Trying to build a complex command in a string causes Very Bad Things to happen; read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 to understand why.

Comment: its working, but what has fixed the immediate closing the window issue?, explain me bit. and also what this do "${cmd[@]}". Thank You

Comment: @user1241903 The "immediate closing window" issue is a gnome-terminal question, not a bash question. Take it up with whoever wrote the blog post saying gnome-terminal could be used that way. `"${cmd[@]}"` expands to the list of entries in the array `cmd`, without changing the boundaries between those entries in any way. In this case, the `cmd` array contains the gnome-terminal command you want to run.